# TCP/IP header bad hdr length 40 - too long

Tags: python, sockets

I am programming in Python a `TCP RST` packet using raw sockets. To do so, I write 1 in the `RST` flag and 0 on the rest, put the windows field to 0 and the urgent field to 0. Then I exchange source and destination port. After that, I recalculate the packet size and create the `IP` header, now with the correct total length IP field.

The pacekts seems fine but this is what I see in tcpdump:

```
IP host-11-0-0-10.http > host-11-0-0-9.37516: Flags [R] [bad hdr length 40 - too long, > 20]
        0x0000:  4500 0028 9ffc 4000 4006 84ad 0b00 000a
        0x0010:  0b00 0009 0050 928c 554c 31d8 0000 0000
        0x0020:  a004 0000 f9b3 0000
```

As far as I see, the IP length is correct (0028 ==> 40 bytes ==> 20 bytes IP and 20 bytes TCP). It is as if it believes the whole header is IP or TCP but I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the TCP header. The `data offset` field (that's what it's called in the RFC but it's often called `header length` too), you have set to 10 (the first nibble of 0xa0 at offset 0x20 in your packet dump). That is the number of 32-bit words in the TCP header -- or the offset of the TCP payload. In this case it should be 5 (20 bytes).

40 is too long because the IP header already specified the total length of the packet, hence there are only 20 bytes left after the IP header.